# How to better troubleshoot a websocket handshake failure in Karate

Tags: websocket, karate, handshake

```
Feature: Verification of wss connectivity of websocket infra test
  Background:
    * url jsonObj.baseUrl
    * callonce read('classpath:common/Login.feature') {loginObj: jsonObj.accountinfo.login2}

  @websocket
  Scenario: Check subscription over wss
    Given def notificationUrl = 'wss://my.test.domain.com/ui-notification/open/'
    * def ws_headers = read('classpath:corejs/ws_headers.js')
    * json options = { headers: '#(ws_headers)' }
    And def handler = function(msg){ return msg.startsWith('{') }
    And def socket = karate.webSocket(notificationUrl, handler, options)
```

Expecting the websocket handshake to work, as all the authorization cookies, we obtain from the reusable feature call, i.e. Login are inherently available throughout the execution scope. 
The content of **ws_headers.js**

```
{
       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,sv;q=0.8',
       'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
       'Connection': 'Upgrade',
       'Host': 'my.test.domain.com',
       'Origin': 'https://my.test.domain.com',
       'Pragma': 'no-cache',
       'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
       'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'XdoghnpRGfqSj8yttPsY0w==',
       'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
       'Upgrade': 'websocket'
}
```

However, get the following exception. Is there a way to get more details about what exactly is failing the hankshake?

```
javascript evaluation failed: karate.webSocket(notificationUrl, handler, options), io.netty.karate.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 302 Found
```

Comment: if you follow this process we can look at it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - it is important that we be able to replicate. else sorry no idea

Comment: sure @PeterThomas. I thought that link was to submit a potential bug only :). About replicating the issue, well I do not have a public url to share, so let me know, submitting it  will make be of value?